# Arduino sketch compiled from Windows or Linux performs differently

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, serial-port, arduino

I have a very strange problem with a sketch which performs differently if compiled and uploaded to Arduino from Windows XP Home sp3 or Elementary OS Luna (a distro of Ubuntu Linux).

This sketch, between other things, reads a byte from a serial connection (bluetooth) and write it back to serial monitor.

This is what I get if I compile the sketch from WinXP: I sent over BT connection strings from "1" to "7" one time each. The ASCII code of these strings are reduced of 48 to transform string in byte. The result is correct, also functions in pointer array are correctly called. 
[image]

and here is what I get from Linux. I sent 4 times each string from "1" to "7" to see that result has nothing to do with what I need to get and also is not consistent with the same input data: for example when I send string "2" I get 104 106 106 104..... and same byte 106 is written with different Strings coming from BT.
Also the functions are not called so it means that is not a Serial.print issue.

[image]

I'm sure it is a compiling issue because once the sketch is uploaded in Arduino it performs in the same way (correct or not) if I use serial monitor in WinXP or Linux.

Here's the sketch

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Streaming.h>
#define nrOfCommands 10

typedef void (* CmdFuncPtr) (); // this is a typedef to command functions

//the following declares an arry of 10 function pointers of type DigitFuncPtr 
CmdFuncPtr setOfCmds[nrOfCommands] = {
  noOp,
  leftWindowDown,
  leftWindowUp,
  bootOpen,
  cabinLightOn,
  cabinLightOff,
  lockOn,
  lockOff,
  canStart,
  canStop
};


#define cmdLeftWindowDown 1
#define cmdLeftWindowUp 2
#define cmdBootOpen 3
#define cmdCabinLightOn 4
#define cmdCabinLightOff 5
#define cmdLockOn 6
#define cmdLockOff 7
#define cmdCanStart 8
#define cmdCanStop 9

#define buttonPin  4     // the number of the pushbutton pin
#define bluetoothTx 2
#define bluetoothRx 3

int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int androidSwitch=0;

byte incomingByte;  // incoming data
byte msg[12];
byte msgLen=0;
byte msgIdMsb=0;
byte msgIdLsb=0;

//const byte cmdLeftWindowDown;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx,bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  //Setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(115200);
  //bluetooth.print("$$$");

  randomSeed(analogRead(10));
  delay(100);
  //bluetooth.println("U,9600,E");
  //bluetooth.begin(9600);
  //time=0;
}

void loop() {
  msgIdLsb=random(1,255);
  msgIdMsb=random(0,5);
  msg[0]=msgIdMsb;
  msg[1]=msgIdLsb;
  msgLen=random(9);
  msg[2]=msgLen;

  for (int x=3;x<msgLen+3;x++) {
    msg[x]=random(255);
  }

  for (int x=3+msgLen;x<11;x++) {
    msg[x]=0;
  }
  msg[11]='\n';
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if ((buttonState == HIGH)||(androidSwitch==HIGH)) {  
    for (int x=0;x<12;x++) {
      Serial<<msg[x]<<" ";
      bluetooth.write(uint8_t(msg[x]));
    }
    Serial<<endl;

  }

  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if(bluetooth.available())
  {
    incomingByte = bluetooth.read()-48;
    Serial<<incomingByte<<endl;
    if (incomingByte<nrOfCommands)
      setOfCmds[incomingByte]();

  }

  delay(10);
}

void noOp(void)
{
  Serial<<"noOp"<<endl;
};

void leftWindowDown(void)
{
  Serial<<"leftWindowDown"<<endl;
};

void leftWindowUp(void)
{
  Serial<<"leftWindowUp"<<endl;
};

void bootOpen(void)
{
  Serial<<"bootOpen"<<endl;
};

void cabinLightOn(void)
{
  Serial<<"cabinLightOn"<<endl;
};

void cabinLightOff(void)
{
  Serial<<"cabinLightOff"<<endl;
};

void lockOn(void) 
{
  Serial<<"lockOn"<<endl;
};

void lockOff(void)
{
  Serial<<"lockOff"<<endl;
};

void canStart(void)
{
  androidSwitch=HIGH;
};

void canStop(void)
{
  androidSwitch=LOW;
};
```

Any help would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: verify you are using the same BT transmitter in both cases. Your output of "Serial<<incomingByte<<endl;" likely is behaving identical, but getting something different. This smells like a UTF issue at the transmitter.

Comment: Have you tried replacing "Serial<<incomingByte<<endl;" with Serial.println(incomingByte);"

Comment: I highly recommend debouncing the input. [suggested debound library](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce-Arduino-Wiring)

Comment: Yes I tried also print(ln) methods but no luck. And yes I'm using the same transmitter. Also to smelles a UTF issue but no idea of how to clarify. At the moment I fixed by installing latest Arduino IDE release (see below). Can you feed an example about how to debounce input from serial transmission? This can be interesting for other purposes.

Comment: the above comment has a link to the GITHUB of the library, with examples.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using the arduino ide; if not, some of the following might not apply.

First, find out the location of the build directory the ide is using when it compiles and links the code.  [One way to find out is to temporarily turn on Verbose output during compilation.  (Click File, Preferences, "Show verbose output during compilation".)  Click the Verify button to compile the code, and look at the path following the -o option in the first line of output.]  For example, on a Linux system the build directory path might be something like `/tmp/build3877126492387157498.tmp`.  In that directory, look for the .cpp file created during compilation.

After you find the .cpp files for your sketch on both systems, copy them onto one system so you can compare them and check for differences.  If they are different, one or the other ide might be corrupt or an incorrect include might be occurring.

If the .cpp files differ, compare the compile flags, the header files, etc.  I think the flags and AVR header files should be the same on both systems, with the possible exception that MSW files might have carriage return characters after the newline characters.  Also check the gcc versions.  [I don't have an MSW system to try, but I'm supposing that gcc is used on both systems for AVR cross-compiling.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.]

If the .cpp files match, then test the generated binary files to find out where they differ.  (For example, if the sketch file is `Blink21x.ino`, binary files might be `Blink21x.cpp.elf` or `Blink21x.cpp.hex`.)  If you have a .elf file on both systems [I don't know if the MSW system will generate .elf] use `avr-objdump` on the Linux system to produce a disassembled version of code:

```
avr-objdump -d Blink21x.cpp.elf > Blink21x.cpp.lst
```

Then use `diff` to locate differences between the two  disassembly files.  Enough information is available in the .lst file to identify your source line if the difference is due to how your source was compiled, as opposed to a difference in libraries.  (In the latter case, enough information is given in the .lst file to identify which library routines differ.)

If you don't have an .elf file on the MSW system, you might try comparing the .hex files.  From the location of the difference you can find the relevant line in the Linux-system .elf-disassembly file, and from that can identify a line of your code or a library routine.

Comment: Thanks for support jwpat7. I "discovered" that under Linux the latest Arduino IDE is not deployed through Software Center (I have rel. 1.0). So I downloaded the latest version from Arduino site (re. 1.0.5) and at the moment I'm no more experiencing this problem. Anyway the above description will be very helpful in case of other troubles, thanks again.